# How Google+ use SHA-1 fingerprint to check valid android apps

Tags: validation, authentication, google-api, fingerprint

I used google plus API to login in my application, I can use it well but I want to know how it works.

Before use google plus API I need to create a client ID by using my SHA-1 fingerprint. So can you explain me when my application connect to Google API Server, how and what mechanism Google uses to detect if my application is valid or invalid?

Thanks.